# Каким образом можно изменить параметры объекта qml из с++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Подскажите пожалуйста: как изменять параметры объекта в `qml-файле` из `cpp-файла.`

У меня есть в `qt` проект с `qml`. В `qml.qrc` есть `Rectangle` и есть параметр `color`. Он прекрасно изменяется из `cpp-файла` путем `->setProperty("color", "black")`, но вот уже параметр `border.color` таким способом я изменить не могу: `->setProperty("border.color", "yellow")`. Таким способом цвет рамки прямоугольника не меняется. В интернете нигде не нашел как менять параметр типа `параметр.параметр` `(border.color`, `border.width` и т.п.)

Comment: а вы уберите кавычки  у  border.color

Comment: без кавычек ругается что `border was not declared in this scope`

Comment: А так `xxx->property("border").value<QObject*>()->setProperty("color", "yellow");`?

Comment: yrHeTaTeJIb, не получаеется. сам qtcreator подсвечивает что для части `->property("border")` мало параметров (там же должно быть типа `->setProperty("параметр", "значение")`, а у меня только "параметр".  `ошибка: no matching function for call to ‘QObject::setProperty(const char [7])’
         rectPatassium->setProperty("border").value<QObject*>()->setProperty("color", "yellow");`
                                            ^

Comment: @el_madcapo, посмотрите еще раз внимательно на мой код и на свой :)

Comment: мой косяк... @yrHeTaTeJIb, большое вам спасибо: все сработало. И неменого продолжая в тему. если вдруг будет вариант типа `параметр1.параметр2.параметр3`, то мне надо будет сделать так: `xxx->property("parametr1").value<QObject*>()->property("parametr2").value<QObject*>()->setProperty("parametr3", "value");` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала доберитесь до нужного объекта, а потом делайте ему `setProperty`.

```
xxx->property("border").value<QObject*>()->setProperty("colo‌​r", "yellow");
```

Если уровней будет больше, продолжайте добираться до последнего:

```
 xxx->property("first").value<QObject*>()->
      property("second").value<QObject*>()->

      //...

      property("last").value<QObject*>()->
      setProperty("colo‌​r", "yellow");
```